# ASP.NET MVC 4 Cannot access Resource files

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a resource file Res.en-US.resx with:

- Build Action: Embedded Resource
- Custom Tool:
  PublicResXFileCodeGenerator and
- Custom Tool Namespace: Resources.Blah

When I try to include them in a .cs page or a razor view, it does not show up at all.  I can't add using or use long namespace to the resource, it simply isn't there.

I want to be able to do:

```
<label>@Resources.Blah.LocationString</label>
```

Ideas?

Comment: Have you included the namespace?

Comment: All I have is MyApp.Web.Controllers/Models/ and Helpers, nothing else shows up.

Comment: Try adding `@using MyApp.Web` to the top of the `.cshtml` file.

Comment: @Alxandr - doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

You need to have one file without dot and another one same name but with dot and something, for example:

Shared.resx
and
Shared.en-GB.resx

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it wasn't working because of the way I named the resource file.  It works once I remove all the "."'s